# Error while Updating SQL table - conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to update trade number for all account where it is missing.

to update a trade number rules are :-

when Postcode for two or more account match then check whether any of the phone number is same or address match with wild card. if any of the crieteria got match than Trade number got updated.

DDL:-

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
 (
 [Account Number] VARCHAR (15),     
 [Trade Number]    VARCHAR (25),
 [ADDRESS 1] VARCHAR (35),
 [BRNAME]    VARCHAR (35),
 [POSTCODE]  VARCHAR (25),
 [Phone Number 1] VARCHAR (8000),     
 [Phone Number 2] VARCHAR (8000),     
 [NEW Phone Number 1]VARCHAR (8000),  
 [NEW Phone Number 2]VARCHAR (8000)
 )

 INSERT @MASTER

 SELECT 'a0001205','',         'UNIT 39',  'SOUTH',    'RM15 4YG',       '07967967404',      '222222222','9988779988',''     UNION ALL  
 SELECT 'a0001205','',         'UNIT 39',  'SOUTH',    'RM15 4YG',     '222222222',      '','',''     UNION ALL        
 SELECT 'a1005338','',         'Unit 3',   'SOUTH',    'RM15 4YG',       '07967967404',   '','',''          UNION ALL  
 SELECT 'a1005338','',         'Unit 3',   'SOUTH',    'RM15 4YG',       '01708865140',   '','',''          UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C5108924','119734','UNIT 39',     'BASILDON', 'RM15 4YG',     '07967967404',   '','',''                      UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C5108924','119734','UNIT 39',     'BASILDON', 'RM15 4YG',     '01708865140',   '','',''                UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C5108965','',         'UNIT 39',  'BASILDON', 'RM15 4YG',     '865140'      ,    '','',''                UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C5108965','',         'UNIT 39',  'BASILDON', 'RM15 4YG',     '865140'      ,      '','',''                UNION ALL
 SELECT 'I0010050','',         'UNIT 39',  'WEST',     'RM15 4YG',        '01708865140',      '01708865140','','55555555'           UNION ALL  
 SELECT 'I0010050','',         'UNIT 39',  'WEST',     'RM15 4YG',        '',   '01708865140','',''           UNION ALL
 SELECT 'I7000438','',         'Unit 3',   'EAST',     'RM15 4YG',        '',      '01708865140','',''                 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'I7000438','',         'Unit 3',   'EAST',     'RM15 4YG',        '55555555',      '01708865140','',''

Code:

;with cte as (
   select o.*, x.FoundTradeNumber
     from @MASTER as o
     cross apply (
       select top 1 FoundTradeNumber = i.[Trade Number]
         from @MASTER  as i
         where REPLACE(i.[POSTCODE], ' ', '')=REPLACE(o.[POSTCODE], ' ', '')
           and nullif(i.[Trade Number],'') is not null
           and (
              nullif(i.[Phone Number 1],0) in (o.[Phone Number 1], o.[Phone Number 2],o.[NEW Phone Number 1], o.[NEW Phone Number 2])
           or nullif(i.[Phone Number 2],0) in (o.[Phone Number 1], o.[Phone Number 2],o.[NEW Phone Number 1], o.[NEW Phone Number 2])
            or nullif(i.[NEW Phone Number 1],0) in (o.[Phone Number 1], o.[Phone Number 2],o.[NEW Phone Number 1], o.[NEW Phone Number 2])
             or nullif(i.[NEW Phone Number 2],0) in (o.[Phone Number 1], o.[Phone Number 2],o.[NEW Phone Number 1], o.[NEW Phone Number 2])
           or i.[ADDRESS 1] LIKE o.[ADDRESS 1]+'%'         
               )
         ) as x
     where nullif(o.[Trade Number],'') is null
      and (o.[Phone Number 1] > 0 or o.[Phone Number 2] > 0 OR o.[NEW Phone Number 1] >0 OR o.[NEW Phone Number 2]>0 )
 )
 --select * from cte
 update cte set [Trade Number] = FoundTradeNumber
```

Error:-

```
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
The conversion of the varchar value '07967967404' overflowed an int column.
```

i am not authorized to change Datatype of column.

Is there any other way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: "Unfortunately i aware keeping Phone number in Varchar is not good practise" - who told you that? also pretty sure a phone number will never be more than 24 digits!

Comment: @MitchWheat: yes You are right. my second task is to clean all bad data using SSIS

Comment: Is there no way to do this. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works, You just need 0 within single quotes ('0')

```
nullif(i.[Phone Number 1],'0')
o.[Phone Number 1] > '0'
```

Result:
[image]